# What's the correct way to read some data from a yaml file and use it in an erb page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm using rails to build a website.

I have a yaml file contails some colors, which is `config/colors.yml`

```
---
- white
- red
- blue
- yellow
- ...
```

And, there is an erb file `app/views/users/setting.html.erb`, which will need the data in `config/colors.yml`, and put them in a  tag.

I don't know what's the correct way to read the yaml file. Can I read once and store them in memory, or I should read it each time the page is requested?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a `config/initializers/load_colors.rb` initializer file with these contents:

```
COLORS = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/colors.yml")
```

This will load the contents of the configuration file into the `COLORS` variable when the Rails application starts. Then you can access the colours from anywhere within the application using `COLORS['section_name']['white']` etc. For example, you could do:

```
<h1 style="color: <%= COLORS['h1']['blue'] %>;">Main Heading</h1>
```

—Although using an inline style like this within a view template isn't really good practice, but it gives you an idea of the usage.

Answer (score 1):

If the colors never change, it's okay to cache them. Follow this [DZone](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6403) tutorial.

3rd result for Google: `ruby yaml tutorial`.